# C - Need help implementing an ADT

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable, abstract-data-type

I'm working on a school assignment and I'm having trouble understanding how to use an ADT. Basically, I need to implement a symbol table ADT that stores `<key, value>` pairs. The value associated with a key is an arbitrary object defined by the user that is passed to the ADT by a void pointer. I have the header file already included, I just need to make the source file for it.

The declaration I am stuck on is for the structure itself. It is a symbol table object pointerd to by a pointer of type `SymTable_T`. It should be able to make copies of `<key, value>` pairs inserted into it and these copies should be destroyed when deleted from the table or when the table itself is destroyed.

The implementation should employ a hash table that uses chaining to resolve collisions. I already am familiar with hashing, so there is no trouble there.

This is what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "symTable.h"
#define DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE 61
#define HASH_MULTIPLIER 65599

typedef struct SymTable *SymTable_T;
{
    char *key;
    int value;
    struct SymTable *next; //linked list
};
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Could someone explain to me the essentials of implementing an ADT? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The essence of an abstract data type is that client code has no insight whatsoever in the structure of values of that type - which also implies that the implementation of any functions dealing with such values is opaque.

In your example, it means that you *do not* define the `struct` in the header file but merely use a forward declaration. For traversal, you may also want to define an equally opaque iterator type, e.g.

```
struct symtable;
struct symtable_iterator;
```

...and then a collection of functions working with the table, e.g.

```
/* Create symtable, destroy it, insert values. */
void symtable_alloc(struct symtable **table);
void symtable_free(struct symtable *table);
void symtable_insert(struct symtable *table, const char *key, void *value);

/* Create symtable iterator, destroy it, access key/value. */
void symtable_iterator_alloc(struct symtable *table, struct symtable_iterator **it);
void symtable_iterator_free(struct symtable_iterator *it);
bool symtable_iterator_next(struct symtable_iterator **it);
const char *symtable_iterator_key(struct symtable_iterator *it);
void *symtable_iterator_value(struct symtable_iterator *it);
```

That's all you should put into the header file. In the implementation (`.c`) file, you would actually define the structure and its fields - but that code is hidden from clients.

You could use them like

```
struct symtable *table;
symtable_alloc(&table);
symtable_insert(table, "one", "eins");
symtable_insert(table, "two", "zwei");
symtable_insert(table, "three", "drei");

struct symtable_iterator *it;
symtable_iterator_alloc(table, &it);
while (symtable_iterator_next(&it)) {
   printf("%s: %s\n", symtable_iterator_key(it), symtable_iterator_value(it));
}
symtable_iterator_free(it);
symtable_free(table);
```

Note how the set of functions clearly defines the API of the data structure, but the actual type is abstract - there's no information which gives away the implementation of the table, e.g. whether it's a linked list or a hash table or something else.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I was already familiar with the header/source files but you clarified quite a bit for me. Can you comment on my structure or perhaps break down the statement `typedef struct SymTable *SymTable_T`? I know that `struct SymTable` is the structure itself, but what is the pointer pointing to?